# Linq to Dictionary<string, string[]>. Select keys with values that contain condition string

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary Dictionary<string, string[]>. How can I select all keys with values that contain string "item1" using Linq?

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    {
        "key1",
        new string[] { "item1", "item2", "item3" }
    },
    {
        "key2",
        new string[] { "item1", "item4" }
    }
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What had you tried? start with `dictionary.Where(kvp ... )`

Comment: ToDictionary only takes to parameters, not sure how you need help. Maybe use groupby first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Where` to filter the `KeyValuePair`s then `Select` to return the keys.

```
var result = dictionary
    .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains("item1"))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```